# 4-cities traveling salesman quantum algorithm (QUBO)

Tags: quantum-algorithms, qubo

A quantum version of the traveling salesman algorithm is discussed [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9l6q-YI4Wo0):

[image]

There is a reference to **QUBO**, **Ising**, and some matrix constructions,

[image]

and the output in the end:

[image]

Is anyone able to run through and help concretely explain (using the 4 cities and distances in the first diagram) what that computation is attempting to do, please?

Answer (score -1):

There seems no efficient algorithm for classically finding the shortest route to the traveling salesman problem.

For connecting the 4 dots A, B, C, D:

[image]

The minimum possible distance is 5, with multiple possible routes.

Suppose distance between cities AB is changed by +1, then the distance table has changed significantly into:

[image] [image]

Thus a single weight change will have global influence on many final states, which need to be rechecked before determining the new shortest route.

If these values could be encoded somehow into tensored quantum state coefficients, then the largest (or smallest in dual formulation) state coefficients will have a higher probability of being the measured state outcome, versus the smallest coefficients.

---

Direct encoding of arbitrary tensored values by manipulating each qubit's entry coefficients is generally not possible. For instance, if

$$\begin{bmatrix} |00\rangle & 1 \\ |01\rangle & 2 \\ |10\rangle 
 & 3 \\ |11\rangle & 4 \end{bmatrix}$$

then

$$\Psi_1 \Psi_2 = (a|0\rangle + b|1\rangle)(c|0\rangle + d|1\rangle) = ac|00\rangle + ad|01\rangle + bc|10\rangle + bd|11\rangle$$

and so

$$ac = 1$$
$$ad = 2$$
$$bc = 3$$
$$bd = 4$$

But then from (1) and (2),

$$\frac{ac}{ad} = \frac{c}{d} = \frac{1}{2}$$

while from (3) and (4),

$$\frac{bc}{bd} = \frac{c}{d} = \frac{3}{4}$$

which causes a contradiction.

---

Spin states computation using Ising model:

[image]

$$H = \sum_{m,n} J_{mn}\sigma_m\sigma_n$$

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

[image]

[image]

Insufficient damping factor vs choose-1 penalties:

[image]

---

$$0 = [1 - \sigma_{a\{0,1\}} - \sigma_{b\{0,1\}} - \sigma_{c\{0,1\}} - \sigma_{d\{0,1\}}]^2$$

$$ 0 = [2 - \sigma_{a\{0,2\}} - \sigma_{b\{0,2\}} - \sigma_{c\{0,2\}} - \sigma_{d\{0,2\}}]^2$$

$$ 0 = [(2-4) - (\sigma_{a\{0,2\}}-1) - (\sigma_{b\{0,2\}}-1) - (\sigma_{c\{0,2\}}-1) - (\sigma_{d\{0,2\}}-1)]^2$$

$$ 0 = [-2 - \sigma_{a\{-1,1\}} - \sigma_{b\{-1,1\}} - \sigma_{c\{-1,1\}} - \sigma_{d\{-1,1\}}]^2$$

[image]